# Add specific user roles to a specific model instance using CanCan and Rolify

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, cancan

As I work may way through a Rails app, I have another question.  The app allows for users to sign up via Devise.  That works.  Within the app, users are able to create their own groups called Circles.  That works.  Now I want the user to be able to add other users to their Circle.  This doesn't work.

So far I've implemented CanCan and Rolify.  I'm able to assign a role to a user from the User model, so I know the setup is working just fine.  What I cannot figure out is how a user can add another user to a specific Circle.  I've looked over SO and found something close to what I want to do here: [Authorization in Rails 3.1 : CanCan, CanTango, declarative_authorization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906237/authorization-in-rails-3-1-cancan-cantango-declarative-authorization), but this doesn't work for my situation.

I know how to add a role at the application level with CanCan.  What I want to do is add a role at the specific Circle instance.  Not all users will have access to a Circle, only those who are added.

I'm open to other ways to accomplish this if anyone has any ideas.  What would be the best way to set this up?

**EDIT**

I figured out how to do this from rails console.  `user.add_role :moderator, Circle.find(22)`  This works perfectly and saves to the database.  How can I do this same thing through a form in a view?

Answer (score 0):

Use a controller....it will add the role after that you submit the form! In the controller you can just use a class method for example:)
Let me know if I need to be more explicit!
Cheers